# How to set background image inside div in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to display image as background and that how it should look below.

```
<ion-thumbnail item-left="" style="background-image: url(http://192.168.90.72:8000/storage/profile/853990510/profile.jpg);background-size: 100%;">
</ion-thumbnail>
```

However I want it to load images dynamically please  see the code below  and unfortunately its not working.

```
<ion-thumbnail  ngStyle="background-image:url('{{ review.owner.profile.photo }}')" item-left>
</ion-thumbnail>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ngStyle` directive like this

```
<ion-thumbnail  [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+ review.owner.profile.photo +')'}" item-left>
</ion-thumbnail>
```

Comment: I am able to make my code work like this. Thank you for your great effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also

**HTML**

```
<ion-thumbnail  [ngStyle]="bgStyle" item-left></ion-thumbnail>
```

**TS**

```
this.bgStyle = {'background-image':`url(${this.review.owner.profile.photo})`}
```

Comment: @malbarmawi yup my bad

Comment: Hi, I need to check this one if this works too in weekdays and I can rate this one. Thank you for your great effort.

Answer (score 0):

**hi, this is a working snippet here.**

```
<div class="img-in-zoom-viewer" style="background-image: url({{ imgURI }})"></div>
```

thus, i hope you do such things below:

```
<ion-thumbnail style="background-image: url({{ review.owner.profile.photo }})" item-left>
</ion-thumbnail>
```

hope it would help you.

Comment: Hi, I need to check this one if this works too in weekdays and I can rate this one. Thank you for your great effort.